# Запятая между однородными придаточными с противительным союзом

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, спп, сложное-предложение, придаточное-предложение

*Для начальника очевидно, что отделу нужен не новый сотрудник, а качественное обучение[,] и тогда отдел будет работать эффективнее.*

Запятая ведь не ставится, верно?

*После последнего однородного члена предложения, присоединяемого противительным или подчинительным союзом и не заканчивающего собой предложения, запятая не ставится (т. е. последний однородный член не обособляется)*

*Для начальника очевидно, что не нужно нанимать нового сотрудника, а нужно внедрить качественное обучение[,] и тогда отдел будет работать эффективнее.*

Но вот здесь запятая ставится, т.к. союз *а* соединяет однородные придаточные

Answer (score 2):

**В обоих случаях запятые ставятся:**

(1) Для начальника очевидно, что отделу нужен не новый сотрудник, а качественное обучение,  **и тогда** отдел будет работать эффективнее.

(2) Для начальника очевидно, что не нужно нанимать нового сотрудника, а нужно внедрить качественное обучение, **и тогда** отдел будет работать эффективнее.

**Пояснение**

**Предложение (1):** Первое придаточное распространено однородными членами.

Почему  ставится запятая?

а) Не может союз И связать  придаточные предложения, если они осложнены (содержат однородные члены).

б) К союзу И относится наречие ***тогда*** (= в таком случае), поэтому отношения не соединительные, а следственно-соединительные.

**Предложение (2):** Три однородных придаточных, связанных союзами А, И.

Почему  ставится запятая?

Это  не тот случай, когда союз И может связать два придаточных в одну фразу.

Comment: Так почему не ставится или почему ставится?

Comment: Потому что эта задача не решается формально: увидел одиночный союз И и решил запятую не ставить (у Розенталя об этом в общих чертах говорится в примечании http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=139,3#pp139). Нужно анализировать степень единства однородных членов и однородных придаточных (они должны составлять одну фразу, без паузы). А если в одном из придаточных есть противительные союзы, то как вы это единство выразите? Обратите внимание на примеры из правил: все конструкции простенькие, неосложненные, именно такие, из которых строится общая фраза при отсутствии запятой.

Comment: Jasmin, мне Ваш ход мысли не понятен. Не могли бы Вы выразить ее как-то так: запятая ставится в таких-то случаях, это именно то, что мы имеем,  запятая не ставится в таких-то случаях, но в нашем предложении это не так. потому что ....

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы я дополнила Розенталя и написала еще одно частное правило?  Но я же не Розенталь, меня  читать не будут. И разве вы не видите, как пользователи понимают эти правила? Так же, как всю пунктуацию, то есть абсолютно формально, правила им нужны только для единообразного написания . Ну могу я, к примеру, написать: Если одно из однородных придаточных содержит противительные союзы при однородных членах, то запятая  между придаточными, связанными одиночным союзом И, не ставится. И кто мне поверит?  А так я хотя бы на примечание могу сослаться, где говорится о разных исключениях.